# Tumblr wrong note count

Tags: tumblr

It seems to me that the tumblr note counts are wrong (even in dashboard),

For example it will say I have 11 notes, when clicking on "11 notes" there are only two notes loaded down the bottom,

The difference in notes is not consistent, nor does there seem to be any pattern,

Is this a Tumblr issue, or an account issue?

[image]

Comment: It's better if you get in touch with Tumblr support - looks more like an issue over at Tumblr. Or perhaps Tumblr is suppressing notes from persons you've blocked

Comment: Tried contacting tumblr at their info@ email but no reply. I have noone blocked so that can't be it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happened to me too. It also happens the other way sometimes (like it says you have 2 notes, but really you have 8). The number it shows you is a glitch. The correct number is the number of notes you actually have (so count it, if you really want to know). But there's also been a glitch where it removes previous notes, so maybe the number being shown is correct because they've hidden your other notes?

Comment: Ambiguous as this answer is, it's correct - Tumblr's note counts have been wrong on and off for a while now.